# PHP Search by divding variable in parts

Tags: php

I have a variable containing `$searhing = Iphone 5GB` and other varaible contains `$search_in = 5GB come in Iphone` what i wanna do is that varaible `$searching` breaks in parts Iphone and 5Gb and then searches in second varaiable, if all parts of the varaible matches to the second varaible then it echos the second variable. Kindly let me know how can we do this sort of searching in PHP. Thanks,

Comment: Check `explode` and `array_intersect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$searching = "iphssone 4gb";
$search_in = "4gb comes in iphone";

$toFind = explode(" ",$searching);
$myString = explode(" ",$search_in);
foreach($toFind as $word)
{
    if(!in_array($word,$myString))
        return false;

}
echo $search_in;
```